# Facebook messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot, facebook-chat

Is there any way I can intercept messages from facebook groups?

1. Tried to add a chatbot to a group, but it's just allowed to add persons to chat group, so I guess chatbot is out of the possibilities.
2. Then I googled and found out that the functionallity for the graph api is alreadry deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

For the record, My goal is to be able to do some actions, based on what people say in a chat group.

Any hints on this? Any workaround is also apreciated.

Comment: No, this isn't supported behavior in Facebook's API to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. You can build a [Chat Extension](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/chat-extensions) to offer functionality that can be invoked in a group chat, but it won't be able to actively listen and participate in the way you are asking about.